# Sorting and Grouping on a list of objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

I have a List of Procedure objects as below

```
Procedure1  01/01/2020
Procedure2  03/01/2020
Procedure3  03/01/2020
Procedure1  04/01/2020
Procedure5  05/01/2020, 02/01/2020
Procedure2  06/01/2020
```

and my Procedure class is like

```
Class Procedure {
    List<Date> procedureDate;
    String procedureName;
}
```

I want to sort and group the objects based on the below conditions.

1. All procedures should be grouped based on the procedure name.
2. Procedures must be in descending order of procedure date. [first element in date list i.e., `procedureDate.get[0]]`
3. Same Procedures grouped together should be in descending order of Date.

End result must be,

```
Procedure2  06/01/2020
Procedure2  03/01/2020

Procedure5  05/01/2020, 02/01/2020

Procedure1  04/01/2020
Procedure1  01/01/2020

Procedure3  03/01/2020
```

I was able to achieve this using Comparator and old java code. Is it possible to achieve the same using java8 streams, collectors and grouping by?

Comment: Please post your "old" code, so that we don't have to entirely rely on guessing, it also improves your question, by showing what you've done and are not just here for someone to write all the code for you

Comment: why is Procedure5  05/01/2020, 02/01/2020 and  not Procedure5  05/01/2020 Procedure5 02/01/2020

Comment: @ ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ Basically this list is derived from a document containing sentences. If the sentence is , "Some Procedure5 happened on 05/01/2020 and 02/01/2020" , there will be 2 dates associated with the Procedure5. If the sentence is "Procendure5 happened on 05/01/2020......and after some days Procedure5 happened on 02/01/2020", it will be Procendure5 - 05/01/2020 and Procedure5 -02/01/2020 (as per business requirement)

Comment: You can just use group function and then sort the result,this way will be easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. The solution is **not as easy as it looks to be**. You have to divide the solution into multiple steps:

1. Get the max value for each grouped `procedureName` based on the first dates in the `List<Date>`.
2. Compare the `Procedure` instances based on max `Date` value from the `Map<String, Date` created in the step one.
3. If they are equal distinguish them by the name (ex. two times `Procedure 2`).
4. If they are still equal, sort the `Procedure` instances based on their actual first date.

Here is the demo at: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/Te.

**Step 1**

```
List<Procedure> procedures = ...

Map<String, Date> map = procedures.stream().collect(
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Procedure::getProcedureName,
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getProcedureDate().get(0)))),
    s -> s.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
              Map.Entry::getKey,
              e -> e.getValue().get().getProcedureDate().get(0)))));
```

.. explained: There is a simple way to get a `Procedure` with maximum first date grouped by `procedureName`.

```
Map<String, Optional<Procedure>> mapOfOptionalProcedures = procedures.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             Procedure::getProcedureName,
             Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getProcedureDate().get(0)))));
```

However, the returned structure is a bit clumsy (`Map<String, Optional<Procedure>>`), to make it useful and return `Date` directly, there is a need of additional downstream collector `Collectors::collectingAndThen` which uses a `Function` as a result mapper:

```
Map<String, Date> map = procedures.stream().collect(
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        /* grouping part */,
        s -> s.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue().get().getProcedureDate().get(0)))));
```

... which is effectively the first snippet.

**Steps 2, 3 and 4**

Basically, sort by the maximum date for each group. Then sort by the name and finally by the actual first date.

```
Collections.sort(
    procedures,
    (l, r) -> {
        int dates = map.get(r.getProcedureName()).compareTo(map.get(l.getProcedureName()));
        if (dates == 0) {
             int names =  l.getProcedureName().compareTo(r.getProcedureName());
             if (names == 0) {
                 return r.getProcedureDate().get(0).compareTo(l.getProcedureDate().get(0));
             } else return names;
        } else return dates;
    }
);
```

**Sorted result**

Using the deprecated `java.util.Date` according to your question, the sorted `procedures` will have sorted items like your expected snippet (I have overrided the `Procedure::toString` method)

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return procedureName + " " + procedureDate;
}
```

```
Procedure2 [Mon Jan 06 00:00:00 CET 2020]
Procedure2 [Fri Jan 03 00:00:00 CET 2020]
Procedure5 [Sun Jan 05 00:00:00 CET 2020, Thu Jan 02 00:00:00 CET 2020]
Procedure1 [Sat Jan 04 00:00:00 CET 2020]
Procedure1 [Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2020]
Procedure3 [Fri Jan 03 00:00:00 CET 2020]
```

Answer (score 1):

My thought is coming from functional programming which is based on map-reduce. You can see groupBy/collect is actually a form of reduce anyway and this problem can be better "merge" rather than using groupBy feature of Stream. This is my implementation in pure Stream.

```
List<Procedure> a = List.of(
    new Procedure(...),
    ...

)


List<Procedure> b = a.stream().map((p)-> {                    // Prepare for reduce by create Map for each object
        Map<String,Procedure> mapP = new HashMap<>();
        mapP.put(p.getProcedureName(),p)
        return mapP
    }).reduce((p,q)->{                                         //Use reduce to merge
        q.entrySet().stream().forEach((qq)-> {
            if (p.containsKey(qq.getKey())) {
                p.get(qq.getKey()).setProcedureDate(
                    new ArrayList<Date>(
                        Stream.concat(
                            p.get(qq.getKey()).getProcedureDate().stream(),
                            qq.getValue().getProcedureDate().stream())
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet()))
                );
            } else {
                p.put(qq.getKey(), qq.getValue());
            }

        })

        return p;
    }).get().values().stream().map(p-> {                          //sort date inside object
            p.setProcedureDate(p.getProcedureDate().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()))
            return p;
        }
    ).sorted((x,y)->                                         //sort object by the first date

        x.procedureDate.get(0).compareTo(y.procedureDate.get(0))

    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Quite impressive. But there is no meaning of `entrySet().stream().forEach()` when `entrySet().forEach()` would do the same.

Comment: @Nikolas I know.. but Stream is asked.. so I answered

Comment: Although the solution using Stream API was asked, it doesn't mean it should be used when it makes no sense.

Comment: @Nikolas According to User_1940878, "I was able to achieve this using Comparator and old java code. Is it possible to achieve the same using java8 streams, collectors and grouping by?" means he/she knows how to do it without stream. So I just answer it with purely stream..